# On the Chinese translation of some words by 歌德

Tags: translation, culture, history, books, literature

I am curious about the official Chinese translation of a few words by 歌德. The first occurs on [this webpage](http://www.lexikus.de/bibliothek/Aphorismen-aus-der-Feder-von-Johann-Wolfgang-von-Goethe) advertised as an aphorism, namely

> Man weicht der Welt nicht sicherer aus als durch die Kunst, und man verknüpft sich nicht sicherer mit ihr als durch die Kunst.

The second occurs in 浮士德 and can be found on [this page](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Seite:Faust_I_(Goethe)_088.jpg) at the very beginning, namely

> Du kannst im Großen nichts vernichten // Und fängst es nun im Kleinen an.

I am pretty sure everything what such a great and important writer as Goethe said was translated to Chinese. Hence, there should be an official Chinese translation of these words. But due to lacking search skills and aquaintance with the Chinese internet, I only find some translation of some of Geothes books behind a paywall.

If you have a copy of Faust at hand, a partial answer for the second word is welcome. But I am also very much interested in the aphorism's translation which might be harder to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common translation for the first one seems to be:

> 要想逃避这个世界，没有比艺术更可靠的途径；要想同世界结合，也没有比艺术更可靠的途径。

It’s all over the net.

Similarly the most popular rendition of the second one looks like:

> 你不能大规模毁灭万物，只得先从小规模开始。

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Chinese version of 歌德的浮士德? Is it freely available online? I would like to look up a few other quotes...